# git merge: how keep master version of file?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm using git and am merging a branch into master after a pull request.

My understanding is that if a file in the master wasn't changed since the last common ancestor, but the same file in the branch was, git will use the version in the branch during the merge.

For most of the differences between the two branches, that's the behavior I desire, but there are a few files in one subdirectory tree for which I want the merge to keep the master version and discard the branch version.

What's a good command-line based workflow for doing that?

Comment: This seems to me more like cherry-picking than merge.

Comment: Perhaps the cleanest solution would be to get whoever submitted the pull request to amend his commits to meet your desires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option is to use `git merge --no-commit --no-ff` to merge everything and stop at the last step before everything is committed. Then you reset/checkout those files that you need to stay the same, then run `git-commit`. You will need to do so whenever you make changes that you do not want merged onto `master`. The risk with this approach is that you might forget about some diffs/files, and they will end up in your colleagues' repositories without apparent reason.

Another option, somewhat more complex, is to create two branches, let us call them `tests` and `features`. Branch `features` contains those changes that you will merge onto `master`, while branch `tests` contains the other changes. Thus you will keep merging `features` onto both `master` and `tests`. This eliminates the risk mentioned above, making this the best option.

A third option is to keep merging and then making commits that revert those things you did not want changed. This makes it harder for your colleagues to understand your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are many ways. What I would do:

1. perform the merge (be sure it won't be a fast forward with --no-ff switch)
2. edit (aka amend) last commit (which will be your merge commit)
3. unstage changed file which you want to 'reset'
4. do a commit (which will be a new merge commit without your file)
5. reset changes in file.

Another way would be to revert all commits which were touching your file (if possible) after merge.